# How to create a high-score system on a python (3.4) code?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code in python (3.4) that is a game. At the end of the game, I want the user to be able to input a username and this will be copied to a text document with their score beside it.

I've tried writing this:

```
c=open("highscore.txt","w")
c.write('Highscore: %s' %name")
c.close()
```

but this just wipes what's in the text file and replaces it with new text.
Can anybody help me with this?

If you need it, the OS i'm using is windows 8.

Comment: "'w' for only writing (an existing file with the same name will be erased), and 'a' opens the file for appending" — see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, it will separate each highscore with newline as well, and it will close automatically:

```
with open("highscore.txt", "a") as c:
    c.write('Highscore: %s\n' % name)
```